# Using Function app connector in ADF - How to override parameters in CI-CD?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need a work around pretty quickly - this was a late surprise in the dev process when we added an Az function to our development ADF pipeline.

When you use a function app in ADF V2, when you generate the ARM template, it does not parameterize the key references unlike in other linked services.  Ugh!

So for CI/CD scenarios, when we deploy we now have a fixed function app reference.  What we'd like to do is the same as other linked services - override the key parameters to point to the correct Dev/UAT /Production environment versions of the functions.

I can think of dirty hacks using powershell to overwrite (does powershell support ADF functions yet?  don't know - in January they didn't).

Any other ideas on how to override function app linked service settings?

the key parameters are under typeProperties (assuming the function key is in keyvault):

```
{"functionAppUrl:="https://xxx.azurewebsites.net"}
{"functionkey":{"store":{"referenceName"="xxxKeyVaultLS"}}}
{"functionkey":{"secretName"="xxxKeyName"}}
```

Right now these are hard coded from the UI settings - no parameter and no default.

Comment: If you use other connection, like to Databricks for example, I would say - add parameter to connection and use 'Advanced' section to specify a dynamic content to replace AppUrl with value from parameter. Unfortunately, Azure Function connector does not allow to define parameters.
As long as Function connection is not supporting parameters - the only solution would be to replace that value (URL) in ARM template in specific path (pointing by name) with token (tokenization). Then use Azure Key Vault or DevOps parameters to replace it with an appropriate value per environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, eventually got back to this.

The solution looks a lot but it is pretty simple.

In my devops release, I create a Powershell task after both the data factory ARM template has been deployed and the powershell task for deployment.ps1 with the "predeployment=$false" setting has run (see ADF CI/CD [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#sample-prepostdeployment-script).)

I have a json file for each environment (dev/uat/prod) in my git repo (I actually use a separate "common" repo to store scripts apart from the ADF git repo and its alias in DevOps is "_Common" - you'll see this below in the -File parameter of the script).

The json file to replace the deployed function linked service is a copy of the function linked service json in ADF and looks like this for DEV:

(scripts/Powershell/dev.json)

```
{
    "name": "FuncLinkedServiceName",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureFunction",
        "typeProperties": {
            "functionAppUrl": "https://myDEVfunction.azurewebsites.net",
            "functionKey": {
                "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                "store": {
                    "referenceName": "MyKeyvault_LS",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "secretName": "MyFunctionKeyInKeyvault"
            }
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "MyintegrationRuntime",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    }
}
```

...and the PROD file would be like this:

(scripts/Powershell/prod.json)

```
{
    "name": "FuncLinkedServiceName",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureFunction",
        "typeProperties": {
            "functionAppUrl": "https://myPRODfunction.azurewebsites.net",
            "functionKey": {
                "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                "store": {
                    "referenceName": "MyKeyvault_LS",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "secretName": "MyFunctionKeyInKeyvault"
            }
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "MyintegrationRuntime",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    }
}
```

then in the devops pipeline, I use a Powershell script block that looks like this:

```
Set-AzureRMDataFactoryV2LinkedService -ResourceGroup "$(varRGName)" -DataFactoryName "$(varAdfName)" -Name "$(varFuncLinkedServiceName)" -File "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Common/Scripts/Powershell/$(varEnvironment).json" -Force
```

or for Az

```
Set-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -ResourceGroupName "$(varRGName)" -DataFactoryName "$(varAdfName)" -Name "$(varFuncLinkedServiceName)" -DefinitionFile "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Common/Scripts/Powershell/Converter/$(varEnvironment).json" -Force
```

Note:

- the $(varXxx) are defined in my pipeline variables e.g.

  - varFuncLinkServiceName = FuncLinkedServiceName.
  - varEnvironment = "DEV", "UAT", "PROD" depending on the target release
- Force is used because the Linked service must already exist in the Data Factory ARM deployment and then we need to force the overwrite of just the function linked service.

Hopefully MSFT will release a function app linked service that uses parameters but until then, this has got us moving with the release pipeline.

HTH.  Mark.

**Update:**  Added the Az cmdlet version of the AzureRM command and changed to Set ("New-Az..." worked but in the new Az - there is only Set- for V2 linked services).